# How to "translate" string into an integer in python?

Tags: python, pandas, string, integer

I have the following df:

```
print(df)
>>>
Marital Status       Income     Education 
  Married             66613       PhD  
  Married             12441       Bachelors 
  Single              52842       Masters Degree
  Relationship        78238       PhD
  Divorced            21242       High School
  Single              47183       Masters Degree
```

I'd like to convert every "String" to a corresponding number (int).
E.g.

"Married" should be **1**

"Single" **2**

"Relationship" **3**

and so on.

I still haven't tried any code yet since I haven't found any reasonable solution after googling for around 1 hour now, but I am sure that the solution is most likely incredibly simple.

Edit: grammar

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This may help you to get what you need.

```py
df['Marital Status'] = df['Marital Status'].astype('category').cat.codes
```

Reference: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html

Comment: Interesting use of category!

Comment: This worked well also for every other string column in the dataframe I wanted to convert to int. Thanks a lot for the elegant solution.

Answer (score 3):

It's exactly what `pd.factorize` do:

```
df['Marital Code'] = pd.factorize(df['Marital Status'])[0] + 1
print(df)

# Output

  Marital Status  Income       Education  Marital Code
0        Married   66613             PhD             1
1        Married   12441       Bachelors             1
2         Single   52842  Masters Degree             2
3   Relationship   78238             PhD             3
4       Divorced   21242     High School             4
5         Single   47183  Masters Degree             2
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution, using `.map`:

```py
df["Marital Status"] = df["Marital Status"].map(
    {"Married": 1, "Single": 2, "Relationship": 3, "Divorced": 4, "Single": 5}
)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   Marital Status  Income       Education
0               1   66613             PhD
1               1   12441       Bachelors
2               5   52842  Masters Degree
3               3   78238             PhD
4               4   21242     High School
5               5   47183  Masters Degree
```

Comment: `map` is the best way to control the number

Answer (score 1):

Another Map solution for a little more readability and control if you wanted to add more later

```
df_map = pd.DataFrame({
    'Text' : ['Married', 'Single', 'Relationship'],
    'Int_Conversion' : [1, 2, 3]
})

df['Education'] = df['Marital'].map(df_map.set_index('Text')['Int_Conversion'])
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach using categories that will work independent of the data:

```
categories = pd.CategoricalDtype(categories=["Married", "Single", "Relationship", "Divorced"], ordered=True)
df["result"] = df["Marital Status"].astype(categories).cat.codes + 1
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
  Marital Status  Income       Education  result
0        Married   66613             PhD       1
1        Married   12441       Bachelors       1
2         Single   52842  Masters Degree       2
3   Relationship   78238             PhD       3
4       Divorced   21242     High School       4
5         Single   47183  Masters Degree       2
```

This approach is suggested by the documentation to control the [behavior](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/categorical.html#controlling-behavior), quote (emphasis mine):

> In the examples above where we passed dtype='category', we used the
> default behavior:
>
> **Categories are inferred from the data**.
>
> **Categories are unordered**.
>
> To control those behaviors, instead of passing 'category', use an
> instance of CategoricalDtype.

Answer (score 1):

By corresponding number. Do you have a specific numbering scheme in mind, or just any number as long as the same string gets the same number assigned?

If the latter, then this code should work.

```
def replace_words(text):
    next_number = 1
    word_map = {}
    
    def get_number(word):
      nonlocal next_number, word_map
      if word in word_map:
        return word_map[word]
      word_map[word] = next_number
      next_number = next_number + 1
      return next_number - 1
    
    words = text.split(" ")
    replaced_words = [get_number(x) for x in words]
    return " ".join([str(x) for x in replaced_words])
    
print(replace_words("some words some thoughts"))
```